Error: ```ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)``` when writing a filter to find links within a message
I write something like anonymous valentines in telegram for a certain audience, and I want to do automatic moderation, but since I work with this for the first time I encountered a problem at the first step, finding links inside messages
import re

def find_markdown_links(message):
    # Regular expression to find Markdown links
    markdown_link_regex = r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\\(\\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'

    # Find all matches
    matches = re.findall(markdown_link_regex, message)

    # Returning the list of found links
    return [(link_text, link_url) for link_text, link_url in matches]


# Example of use
message = "Look at [my website](https://example.com)!"
links = find_markdown_links(message)
for link_text, link_url in links:
    print(f"Link text: {link_text}, URL: {link_url}")

As a result, I get this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AkaiKage\PycharmProjects\test0\main.py", line 34, in <module>
    links = find_markdown_links(message)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AkaiKage\PycharmProjects\test0\main.py", line 29, in find_markdown_links
    return [(link_text, link_url) for link_text, link_url in matches]
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

P.S. It is a filter to find links in telegram messages, which should look for both formatted links in words and regular ones

What exactly is your question?

Your regex has no capturing groups, so matches is a list of strings, not a list of tuples. Either use capturing groups in your regex or change your list comprehension.

I think your regex is not matching what you think it is matching - in your example "Look at [my website](https://example.com)!" it won't match both "my website" and url, it will only match url. See https://regex101.com/r/N6ROWu/1

The current error occurs because the regex only returns URLs as single items, but the code tries to unpack them as pairs.
Try this:
def find_links(message):
"""
Find both Markdown-formatted links and plain URLs in a message.

Args:
    message (str): The message to search for links
    
Returns:
    list: A list of tuples containing (text, url) for formatted links
          and (url, url) for plain URLs
"""
# Regular expression for Markdown links [text](url)
markdown_pattern = r'\[([^\]]+)\]\((https?://[^\s\)]+)\)'

# Regular expression for plain URLs
url_pattern = r'(?<![\[\(])(https?://[^\s\)\]]+)'

links = []

# Find all Markdown-formatted links
markdown_links = re.findall(markdown_pattern, message)
links.extend(markdown_links)

# Find all plain URLs
plain_urls = re.findall(url_pattern, message)
# For plain URLs, use the URL as both the text and the link
links.extend((url, url) for url in plain_urls)

return links


it helped, thank you very much
